# Libtool install warning: xxx.la has not been installed in /user/local/lib

Tags: autotools, automake, libtool

While using `autoreconf` & `automake` & `libtool` to build and install my application, I always get warning "**libtool: warning: xxx.la has not been installed in /user/local/lib**" and "**libtool: warning: remember to run 'libtool --finish /usr/local/lib**". I have tried many methods, e.g., cleaning the project, and reconfigure with make clean, but still can't get rid of the warning. Here is what I tried:

```
./configure
make clean
make
make install prefix=~/Software/
```

Here is part of my `configure.ac` that relates to `automake` and `libtool`.

```
AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([subdir-objects -Wall -Werror])
LT_INIT([dlopen])
```

Why are these warnings emitted, and how do I get rid of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may be a little late, but I was having the same problem. It went away after I did a `make clean` followed by regenerating my "configure" script with `autoreconf`. After that doing the standard `./configure --prefix=...` followed by `make` and `make install` no longer showed the error. Good luck!

Comment: It looks like `libtool` simply does not support install-time relocation via `DESTDIR` or whatever (confirmed by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32766842/1879042)), and will always try to look in the `--libdir` specified at configure time, no matter how many times you run `autoreconf`.

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, it look like it is possible to patch the `libtool` script by inserting `$DESTDIR` into the line `libfile="$libdir/"………` which is luckily unique in the entire file. This needs to be done just once after the script was generated (or updated), and can be accomplished automatically by running `perl -p -i -e 's#^(\s*libfile=")(\$libdir/)#$1\$DESTDIR$2#' libtool`.

Comment: The previous patch prevents the warning "*$lib has not been installed in $libdir*". To also get rid of the warning "*remember to run \`libtool --finish $libdir\`*", one can run `perl -p -i -e 's#^(\s*if test "X\$destdir" = "X)(\$libdir")#$1\$DESTDIR$2#' libtool`. Note, however, that I have no idea what side effects these patches have in the most general case.

Comment: Have you tried contacting `libtool` upstream with your findings?