# how to build apache httpd 2.* and beyond on msys2

Tags: apache, msys2

httpd build on msys2 fails with the following error:

```
xml/apr_xml.c:35:19: fatal error: expat.h: No such file or directory
```

On real linux distros, installing the expat-devel package seems to solve the problem [see here](https://forum.directadmin.com/showthread.php?t=54982), 
more precisely, expat-devel is an apr-util prerequisite
and at least its headers ar missing on msys2.

So how to build httpd with msys since no expat-devel package or headers is available ?
When configuring httpd --with-included-apr, where do apr-utils look for expat headers or how to configure that ?

more precisely the [CHANGES-APR-UTIL-1.6](https://www.apache.org/dist/apr/CHANGES-APR-UTIL-1.6) documentation says

> Changes with APR-util 1.6.0
>
> *) The expat dependency of apr-util is no longer built with
>   apr-util.
>        Install expat (including development headers and libraries) first
>        before building apr-util.

where should expat headers and libs be installed in httpds build directory tree ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally had to build expat separately,
then other errors arised and found a solution thanks to 
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766609/libtool-installation-issue-with-make-install) link for missing libtool and to [that](http://apache-http-server.18135.x6.nabble.com/Problems-building-httpd-2-4-26-with-apr-1-6-2-and-apr-util-1-6-0-td5037972.html) link for the effective way to build expat without generating export redefinition.

let find the full build script here:

```
pacman -S make gcc libcrypt perl unzip libtool msys/libcrypt-devel

cd OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable
curl http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/apache/httpd/httpd-2.4.38.tar.gz --output httpd-2.4.38.tar.gz
tar xvf  httpd-2.4.38.tar.gz

cd $HOME
git clone --branch OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable https://github.com/openssl/openssl.git
mv openssl  OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable
cd OpenSSL_1_1_1-stable
./configure gcc --prefix=$HOME/openssl
make
make install

cd $HOME
wget https://github.com/libexpat/libexpat/releases/download/R_2_2_6/expat-2.2.6.tar.bz2
tar xjvf expat-2.2.6.tar.bz2
cd $HOME/expat-2.2.6
./configure --prefix=$HOME/httpd --exec-prefix=$HOME/httpd
make
make install

cd $HOME
curl http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/apache//apr/apr-1.6.5.tar.gz --output apr-1.6.5.tar.gz
tar xvf apr-1.6.5.tar.gz
curl http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/apache//apr/apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz --output apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz
tar xvf apr-util-1.6.1.tar.gz
cd $HOME/apr-1.6.5
./configure --prefix=$HOME/httpd
 make
 make install
cd $HOME/apr-util-1.6.1
 ./configure --prefix=$HOME/httpd --with-apr=$HOME/httpd --with-expat=$HOME/httpd 
 make
 make install

cd $HOME
wget https://ftp.pcre.org/pub/pcre/pcre-8.43.tar.gz
tar xvf pcre-8.43.tar.gz
cd pcre-8.43
./configure --prefix=$HOME/pcre
make 
make install

cd $HOME
wget https://github.com/nghttp2/nghttp2/releases/download/v1.37.0/nghttp2-1.37.0.tar.gz
tar xvf nghttp2-1.37.0.tar.gz
cd $HOME/nghttp2-1.37.0
./configure  --exec-prefix=$HOME/httpd --prefix=$HOME/httpd
make 
make install

cd $HOME/httpd-2.4.38
 ./configure --prefix=$HOME/httpd --with-expat==$HOME/httpd --with-apr-util=$HOME/httpd --with-apr=$HOME/httpd --with-pcre=$HOME/pcre --enable-ssl --enable-ssl-staticlib-deps --with-ssl=$HOME/openssl --enable-proxy --enable-proxy-connect --enable-proxy-http --enable-proxy-balancer --enable-http2 --enable-nghttp2-staticlib-deps --with-nghttp2=$HOME/nghttp2
make
make install
```

The build process completed successfully, 
but usefull to say that the runtime can't be used since httpd is not able to load its dynamic modules  as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55235233/1767316)